# Laravel5 ORM update - undefined property from variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

***Description:***
I am creating a game, where you can upgrade your buildings. After clicking on any building, it will be upgraded to higher level by upgradeBuilding() method. The most problematic part is that I have to upgrade a building that will be in `$building` variable, it is always a string with name of the building. I think that the `$currentBuildingLevel->{$building}` is causing the error. The second problem is that whenever I try `var_dump($currentBuildingLevel)` its loading crazy long, its not just a simple object with levels of the buildings...

***Database:*** In database `buildings` table, the levels look like this:
[image]

***Building model:*** Here is the code that should update a building level in above record:

```
$building = "barracks"  // example building

public function upgradeBuilding($building)
{
     $currentBuildingLevel = $this->first()->where("user_id", "=", Auth::id());     
     $currentBuildingLevel->{$building} = $currentBuildingLevel->{$building} + 1;
     $currentBuildingLevel->save();
}
```

***Error:*** I am getting an error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$barracks
```

***Question:*** How do I do this properly? Is `$currentBuildingLevel` a model's object already?

Comment: move `first()` into the end of the query `$this->where("user_id", "=", Auth::id())->first();`

Comment: @RavishaHesh Thank you for your advice, does it make any difference?

Comment: yup, `$this->first()` gives you an instance of your model, so you can't use `where()` on that, `where()` function is part of "Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder" class.

Comment: @RavishaHesh Oh, looks like I will have a lot of reading tonight. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a property on `Builder` instead of your actual model because you never complete your query (with `first()`).

You can solve this by 3 options.

Move your `first()` call to the end:

```
$currentBuildingLevel = $this->where("user_id", "=", Auth::id())->first();
```

Or use the instance you're already working on:

```
$this->{$building} += 1;
$this->save();
```

Or [update your column](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#updates) in your controller with an sql query without fetching the data first:

```
Building::where('user_id', Auth::id())->increment($building);
```

Comment: I will check that as soon as I get home. Thank you for your answer, I was struggling with that since yesterday :P